# Should I use Google login with Node backend or Next auth?

Tags: node.js, next.js, jwt, google-signin, next-auth

I have some experience with React but I'm new to Next. Im building out an application and using Next as the frontend with Node backend. I have 2 options to authenticate:

- via Credentials
- via Google

After some research, next auth seems to be a good option to handle authentication for the web app but for my backend apis, I'm protecting them through JWT. If I use credentials providers, everything works well but by using Google providers its generating its own JWT.

How do I use Google provider's JWT with my node backend or is it a better idea to login through google using my node backend?

Comment: did you find the solution? If yes then please do share here

Comment: im looking for the same question. Did you find anything ?